# How to detect prefers-color-scheme change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I can use `window.matchMedia` to detect whether user is in dark mode, but how to listen dark mode change event?

Is there any API like:

```js
window.addEventListener('perfers-color-scheme-change', () => {
  // do something
})
```

Comment: You can just use `matchMedia` as specified here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-detect-a-users-preferred-color-scheme-in-javascript-ec8ee514f1ef/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can add an event-listener with callback on the [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) returned by [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```js
function activateDarkMode() {
  // set style to dark
}

// MediaQueryList
const darkModePreference = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

// recommended method for newer browsers: specify event-type as first argument
darkModePreference.addEventListener("change", e => e.matches && activateDarkMode());

// deprecated method for backward compatibility
darkModePreference.addListener(e => e.matches && activateDarkMode());
```

**Note:**
There are two method versions to register an event-listener:

1. the recommended [`addEventListener("change", listener))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which allows more fine-grained assignment to event-types
2. the deprecated [`addListener(listener)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener)

#### See also

- Medium (2019): [Use “prefers-color-scheme” to detect macOS dark mode with CSS and Javascript](https://medium.com/@jonas_duri/enable-dark-mode-with-css-variables-and-javascript-today-66cedd3d7845)

---

Thanks to [lukaszpolowczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2908501/lukaszpolowczyk) for pointing out that method `addListener(listener)` has become deprecated and to [AsukaSong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7957792/asukasong) for initiating a complete rewrite of this answer.

Comment: Current version : `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener("change",
  e => e.matches && activateDarkMode()
);`

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk Thanks for your hint. Credited you & hope this addition reflects your comment properly

Answer (score 14):

With initialization setter and 'change' listener.

```
const colorSchemeQueryList = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  
const setColorScheme = e => {
  if (e.matches) {
    // Dark
    console.log('Dark mode')
  } else {
    // Light
    console.log('Light mode')
  }
}
  
setColorScheme(colorSchemeQueryList);
colorSchemeQueryList.addEventListener('change', setColorScheme);
```

Answer (score 4):

In React, a great way to do this is to create a custom hook like so

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export const useTheme = () => {
    const initialTheme = darkTheme;
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(initialTheme);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', (e) => e.matches && setTheme(darkTheme));
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').addEventListener('change', (e) => e.matches && setTheme(lightTheme));
    }, []);
    return theme;
};
```